# "Non-Retail" House Battery

Tags: solar-panels, battery, solar

I need a ~3.5kw battery to power an emergency circuit if the power goes down.  I've been quoted $13,000 to add an LG Chem 9kw to our existing system but that does not include the inverter upgrade.  Tesla batteries are even more expensive.

There must be a better way...

I have a relatively large solar array and I'd like to reallocate three or four panels to power a dedicated battery charging circuit using a "non-retail" battery bank.  Not a slipshod hackjob battery, but something safe that that works "good enough" to provide emergency power to certain appliances.

My idea is to reallocate three or four panels (1.1kwh - 1.5kwh) to a small "off grid" inverter that charges a battery bank.  That whole circuit will be wired into the house panel via a critical panel that will keep the vital appliances running overnight (during a power outage) -and- indicate to the main solar inverter that there is power which will keep the main PV system running when the sun comes up (grid tied systems shut down during blackouts; backfeed safety).

Basically:
1.) Normal operation would have the battery charge during the day and deplete as the sun goes down every day.  It's only going to be a small ~3.5kw battery so it will not last long.  It might give us an hour of twilight run time during summer months when the air conditioning is drawing a lot of power.
2.) During power outages the battery will only power a critical panel (key appliances) and serve to keep the main PV system running during the day.
3.) If the blackout occurs after the bank is depleted, the bank will recharge the following morning which will provide enough power to re-activate the main PV array (right?).

My two main questions:
1.) will this work?
2.) will I still have backfeed protection?  I DO NOT want to create a safety hazard for linemen working to restore power.

Comment: What loads are you hoping to power via this system?  Also I think you may be mixing up kW and kWh -- solar panels produce power, measured in kiloWatts, whereas batteries store energy, measured in kiloWatt-hours.  A solar panel that produces a constant 1 kW will generate 1 kWh of energy every hour.  But how many watts of their stored energy a battery can output at a time is a separate spec, which is also important, so we also need to know how fast you're planning to drain them, essentially.

Comment: Also, why are you thinking your battery would deplete every day when there's *not* a power outage?  To minimize wear and tear on it, you should plan to only discharge it when you really need to, when utility power is not available.

Comment: You're right, I was careless with the units.  The battery would deplete daily as I would want it to carry us as far as possible through our peak billing hours, especially in summer months.  I have not figured out the rate of discharge yet.  I want to make sure this setup will not pose a backfeed risk.  If there is a backfeed risk, I'd like to know how to eliminate it.

Comment: Most grid-tie inverters are picky enough about grid quality that most off-grid inverters won't fool them, or at least that was the case when I looked into that question a while ago. You appear to have significant "backfeed risk" but have not clarified desired operation to a point where it seems feasible to sort out how to eliminate that, given multiple overlapping desires that lead that way - i.e. "keeping the grid-tie solar system up" is absolutely contra-indicated - an important part of what makes it grid-tie is that it goes down when the grid does.

Comment: @acpilot, okay, using the battery to shift your demand to a different billing period is a very different use case than just using it to survive power outages -- you aught to add that you're planning on that as well to the question.  Doing that right requires a different, and usually more expensive, system configuration than just a backup system for power outages.  You also need to consider if the wear-and-tear on your very expensive battery is worth the typically rather minor cost savings -- have you run the numbers on this with your specific billing rates yet?

Comment: Have you considered using an AC-coupled battery?  That topology may serve you well here, and I notice one of the Enphase ones is roughly the size you want, 3.3kWh for ~4k, and depending on what you've got now, you may not even need to change out your inverters.  (this is not an endorsement; I haven't used them personally, but it looks like they may meet your needs well) https://www.solarelectricsupply.com/encharge-3-battery

Comment: Here's a better link describing the Enphase offering: https://enphase.com/en-us/homeowners-storage-solutions

Comment: Can you describe your current solar system to us please?

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- actually, most GT inverters *will* run off of a multimode or off-grid inverter's grid, but that sort of AC coupling limits you to a maximum GT inverter wattage equal to the multimode inverter's wattage to allow the multimode to control the grid parameters when it disconnects from the utility

Comment: My experience with this type of system is it sounds cool but never even comes close to paying for itself when there is a grid tie. The batteries have a limited life and the number of charge cycles and depth of charge can be calculated. You will find this costs many times what a simple generator costs and you can fill a generator if gasoline or change tanks if propane or not worry at all if natural gas. Batteries are more expensive and will not last that long if used regularly so the ROI is a huge negative for the short use on a grid tied system. Sell the power and buy a generator it cost less

Comment: Agree on all counts.  Part of the appeal is an automatic transfer and coverage when we are not home.  The generator is an option and we have gas plumbed in but you still need to haul the generator out and fire it up (and hope it works).  Also, we will use the battery every day which will offset some of the cost where the generator will only provide power for a few hours or maybe days per year, else it just sits there taking up space and corroding.